# How to link to specific answer or comment?

Tags: discussion, answers, comments, hyperlinks

As the title.

Sometimes I want to link to specific answer or comment, because the current question or comment will directly benefit from *that* particular answer or comment.

For example: I saw a comment about undead and was inspired to ask a question, or answer. For clarity, I want to include the link to the comment (because copy pasting it will not provide sufficient background on the question/answer)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

There's usually a time next to the username... you can use that to get the link for a comment

For an answer, you can use the share link
[image]

Comment: Thanks! Learning more everyday!

Answer (score 5):

Comments are meant to be ephemeral and may be removed later.  So, don’t link to comments in posts.  If the comment contains important information, it *should be part of the post* and this is a good reason to edit that answer (and then mark the comment as obsolete).

That's why there is no easily accessible URL for a comment.  They do exist, for notifications and moderation, but you should not use them otherwise except in chat.

Comment: I made a comment on a post earlier today that referenced another comment, I included the relevant part of the comment and (attempted) a link to it as well; limited character length broke that (I removed the question title from the url, but that ended up not linking directly to the comment), but it was close enough (it ended up linking to the answer, but the comment was the second one on it, so I left it as-is). I figure that usage is pretty kosher though.